# calling data from restapi and parssing into table in the ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body>
  <table id =101>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>category</th>
    <th>color</th>
  </tr>
    <div>
    </div>

  </table>
<script>
var url  = "http://34.201.147.118:3001/getAllData";
var xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', url, true)
xhr.onload = function () {
    var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(users)
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
    var obj= users
    console.table(obj);
    var tbl=$("#101").attr("id","mytable");//The attr() method set the id attribute to mytable  this method is used to return the attribute value, it returns the value of the FIRST matched element.When this method is used to set attribute values, 


    $("#div1").append(tbl);
    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
    {
        console.log(obj.length)
        var tr="<tr>";
        var td1="<td>"+obj[i]["id"]+"</td>";
        var td2="<td>"+obj[i]["name"]+"</td>";
        var td3="<td>"+obj[i]["category"]+"</td>";
        var td4 ="<td>"+obj[i]["color"]+"</td></tr>";

       $("#mytable").append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4);

    }

        console.table(users);
    } else {
        console.error(users);
    }
}





</script>
</body>
</html>
```

1. i have created a table on my html page and i want call my rest api  and get 
   data .from rest api And parse into table which i created in ui
2. but my code is not entering to onload function  i think i
   went    wrong somewhere plese correct me
3. and i want to print NA if any field in the table is  left empty
4. plese suggest any code changes
5. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to `send()` the XHR. Also, don't try to `parse` the response before the XHR is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code and Update your param in the loop.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
  <style>
table, td, th {
border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
</style>
</head>
 <body>
  <table id='mytable'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>category</th>
<th>color</th>
  </tr>
<div>
</div>

  </table>
<script>


$(document).ready(function(){
var url  = "http://34.201.147.118:3001/getAllData";
$.getJSON(url, function( data ) {
    var obj = data['AllData'];
    for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++)
    {
        var tr  ="<tr>"+
                "<td>"+obj[i]["id"]+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+obj[i]["name"]+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+obj[i]["category"]+"</td>"+
                "<td>"+obj[i]["color"]+"</td></tr>";
       $("#mytable").append(tr);
    }
});
}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you explain what is  data['AllData'] in your code

Comment: I used data['AllData']  to get AllData key from the response because items are inside the AllData. Let me know if any query.

Answer (score 0):

Just think about it ;-) I think you should do it that way.

```
var data = {  //A object
  get: function() { //Your get method
    var url = "http://34.201.147.118:3001/getAllData";
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(responseText) {
        var users = JSON.parse(responseText);
        this.output(users); //Call output method
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(response) {
        console.error(response);
      }
    });
  },


  output: function(users) { //Your output method
    console.log(users.length);

    users.forEach(function(user) {
      var tr = "<tr>";
      var td1 = "<td>" + user.id + "</td>";
      var td2 = "<td>" + user.name + "</td>";
      var td3 = "<td>" + user.category + "</td>";
      var td4 = "<td>" + user.color + "</td></tr>";

      $("#mytable").append(tr + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4);
    });
  }
}

data.get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your support  
on paper seems fine but i am getting following  error
VM255:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (gettingalldataandconvertingintotable.html:40)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)
(anonymous) @ gettingalldataandconvertingintotable.html:40
u @ jquery.min.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
k @ jquery.min.js:2

Comment: Then something is wrong with the string to be converted to JSON.